# How to redirect non www to www in nginx in multi domain environment

Tags: nginx, web-hosting, linode

I have multiple domains registered at on service provider and hosting on linode with nginx.

The example of domain name is www.example.com (not example.com)

All the domains are working fine with www but without it the page does not load.

```
In curl -I http://example.com
```

it results

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host http://example.com
```

I have 3 A/AAAA Records for each separately

```
blank    IP
mail     IP
www      IP
```

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com; 
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error error;

        root /var/www/examplecom/public;
        index index.html index.php;

        location ~ \.php?$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-main.socket;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            #Prevent version info leakage
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I have also tried by writing the second server block on top but same result.

Kindly immediate guideline/help is required.

Comment: `Could not resolve host` — means you should configure your DNS properly

Comment: DNS can take some time to propagate. Assuming your A record stated as 'blank' is actually blank (the root-level 'example.com' and not 'blank.example.com'), your DNS config looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for response.

By the way the problem was resolved when I changed my domain name in linode settings from www.example.com to example.com